# drop the LSB from an address in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to drop (meaning zero the bit) the LSB from an address. The below piece of code which I wrote doesnt seem to do the thing I intended to do.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
struct node
{
    unsigned long key;
    struct node* child[2];
};
int main()
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("%x\n",node);
    node = (struct node*)((uintptr_t) node >> 1UL);
    printf("%x\n",node);
}
```

Comment: And what _did_ you intend to do?

Comment: You need to include in your question the output of the above code, why you feel that it is incorrect, and what the output you would like for it to be.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if your intent is to zero the LSB or shift by 1, either of which could be called "dropping". Please clarify your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clear the least significant bit, you can use:

```
(struct node*)((uintptr_t) node & (UINTPTR_MAX << 1))
```

but don't assign the result to `node` or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: I'm already doing this as `(struct node*)((uintptr_t) p &  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE)`

Comment: I wanted to know if I can do this without using the `&` operator and by just using the bit-wise operator

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator, what do you mean?

Comment: :) I meant using the shift operator!!

Comment: You could use the shift operator twice: ((x >> 1) << 1).  Not that that is a good solution.

Comment: @arunmoezhi see answer from Jashaszun but it will take one operation more

Comment: Ya got it thanks. I'll stick to `&` :)

Comment: @arunmoezhi but you should explain what do you want to achieve with that because it looks highly suspicious.

Comment: I make sure the address returned by `malloc` is byte-aligned and the lsb is always zero. So I use that as a flag in my code. So to get back the original address I just drop the bit.

Comment: @arunmoezhi The object returned by `malloc` is already guaranteed to be aligned for any use.

Comment: The flag part is explained in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389243/stealing-bits-from-a-pointer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the shift operator (as indicated in your comment on `ouah`'s answer), you can use:

```
(struct node*)(((uintptr_t)node >> 1) << 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to zero the low order bit of a value you would use an expression like:

```
x = z & ~1; // assuming x, y, and 1 are of the same bit width
```

This complements `1`, turning it into something like `0b111111...1110` and performs a bitwise `AND` with the value `z`. The effect is the lowest bit is set to `0` while all others retain their values.

The expression you used, `node >> 1UL`, performs a shift -- that is, the bit in position `31` is moved to position `30`, `30` to `29`, ..., and `1` to `0`, and the lowest order bit is discarded. It is usually equivalent to an integer division by 2. If this is what you intended, you should have gotten it.

Comment: Note that when you say `the bit in position 31 is moved to position 30`, that may not be the first bit moved (`1UL` does not need to be 32 bits).

Comment: Also note that `~1` is equivalent to `-2`, and that both should be casted to the correct size.