# pass a structure to gcc built-ins for atomic accesses

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I have a two structures just like below:

```
template <class T>
struct pointer_t
{
    T *ptr;
    uintptr_t tag;
};


template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    pointer_t<Node<T> > next;
};
```

and now I want to pass for example `pointer_t<Node<T> > newNext` to `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap()` function. According to the prototype of the function I pass:

`__sync_bool_compare_and_swap((unsigned long*) &newTail.ptr->next, oldNext, newNext)`

The problem is that if I don't cast `newNext` to `unsigned long` I'll get:

```
error: ‘struct pointer_t<Node<int> >’ used where a ‘long unsigned int’ was expected
      if ( __sync_bool_compare_and_swap((unsigned long*) &newTail.ptr->next, newNext, newNext) )
```

if I cast it to unsigned long then:

```
if ( __sync_bool_compare_and_swap((unsigned long*) &newTail.ptr->next, (unsigned long) oldNext, (unsigned long) newNext) )
```

I'll get:

```
error: ‘struct pointer_t<Node<int> >’ used where a ‘long unsigned int’ was expected.
```

can someone explain me you can I use __sync_bool_compare_and_swap with these two structures?

thanks

Comment: Why are you casting to `unsigned long` when the function wants `long unsigned int` ?

Comment: my mistake, but still I got the same error for casting:
invalid cast from type ...

Comment: Your struct will be too wide for that cast on a 64b platform.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to use tagged pointers??

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use tag pointer. I find out pat of my problem. The problem is that I should just send pointer and pointer to a pointer to the function in order to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct pointer_t
{
    T *ptr;
    uintptr_t tag;
};


template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    pointer_t<Node<T> >* next;
};

int main()
{
    Node<int> *newTail = new Node<int>();
    pointer_t<Node<int> > *oldNext = newTail->next;


    Node<int> *newNext = new Node<int>();

    pointer_t<Node<int> >* newNextPtr = new pointer_t<Node<int> >();
    newNextPtr->ptr=newNext;

    if ( __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&newTail->next, oldNext, newNextPtr)) {
        std::cout<<"Gotcha!\n";
      }
 }
```

Which doesn't really solve your pointer tagging problem. If you want to achieve pointer tagging then, just steal a few unused bits from the pointer and set those bits to tag the pointer, then unset them to reset the pointer. Don't forget to untag the bits before dereferencing.

```
#define get_markedness(p) (((ptr_int) (p)) & 3)
#define get_unmarked_reference(p) ((void *) (((ptr_int) (p)) & (~3)))
#define get_marked_reference(p,m) ((void *) (((ptr_int) (p)) | m))
```

Comment: Thanks! very helpful but I have two questions.
First, in my definition for Node for `pointer_t` I didn't use pointer to `pointer_t` am I wrong? Since I thought if I don't use pointer then I don't have to acquire memory for each node two times, instead with single new I'll also take memory for the pointer, but with this attitude when I want to do atomic operation I face with problem.
My second question is that I didn't get yer last point, sorry but can you explain it more? It seems interesting for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the links below, if you find pointer marking interesting

[stealing bits from a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389243/stealing-bits-from-a-pointer)

http://concurrencyfreaks.blogspot.se/2014/03/harriss-linked-list.html

https://timharris.uk/papers/2001-disc.pdf